# How to reset just one field in a form on submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with two fields that I submit with Ajax using JQuery. On submit I want to reset just one of the fields that's a textarea. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you try so far? What **exactly** is the problem? (what is it that you don't know how to do?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/357/)**.

You could simply use the jQuery method **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**:

```
$('selector').val('');
```

**HTML sample :**

```
<form id='my-form'>
  <textarea id='area1'></textarea>
  <textarea id='area2'></textarea>

  <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#my-form').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $('#area1').val('');
})
```

Hope this helps.